# Several redundant automatic entries for all DHCP client machine host names in Samba 4 AD DC DNS

Tags: dhcp, internal-dns, samba4, dynamic-dns

We have a Samba 4 AD DC installation wich is also the DNS in our network.

It collects entries of all DHCP client machines with their addresses automatically. I can remember to have activated this behavior some day in the past, but can't remember where this had been. Of course I assumed it will drop old entries and not just collect new ones.

The screenshot explains it way better: [DNS Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoYuf.png)

Any idea where this setting can be?
Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

If your asking how to automatically clean up stale DNS entries then you need to enable Scavenging on the DNS server and enable Aging on the DNS zone.

Comment: Actually I wanted to switch off the automatically added entries for the DHCP clients, but this also a way to go.
Thanks for the suggestion.